# How to handle authentication for GitLab AND ownCloud?

Tags: ldap, gitlab, owncloud

I'm running GitLab and ownCloud on my webserver. I use it mainly for myself, but I want to let some of my friends use it for some projects. My problem: I want to centralize the authentication process. This means I only want one account for OwnCloud and GitLab. I know both support LDAP as authentication backend. However, are there any restrictions I that might encounter?

Answer (score 0):

GitLab CE only allows one LDAP Server and one base DN so keep that in mind if you decide to how you organize your domain. ownCloud on the other hand supports multiple servers and base DN. Don't forget to create a user which will read from the active directory to check credentials.